# Error raised when using HTMLToPDF on Windows

Tags: python, html2pdf, html-to-pdf

I am trying to convert HTML into PDF using html2pdf.HTMLToPDF

An error is raised and seems to have something to do with me working on Windows. How can I avoid this or which other function can I use ?

```
ValueError: close_fds is not supported on Windows platforms if you redirect stdin/stdout/stderr
```

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/html2pdf/0.1

Comment: windows isn't currently supported, see the system requirements

Comment: I'd recommend using https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfkit

Comment: pdfkit works well on windows, thanks !